# Looking for the name of a book about a female scientist who travels back in time and falls in love with a Viking king named Per

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, love

I read a book around 1998-2000, which was about a group of (U.K./English?) scientists who had created a time machine.

One of them, a female, travelled back in time and arrives in the time of the Vikings.

She falls in love with Per, who I think was the Viking king or perhaps the prince.

I can't remember the name of the author or the book, and I'd love to find out if anyone knows/remembers this book!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is almost certainly [The Sterkarm Handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sterkarm_Handshake) by Susan Price.

The time machine is a tunnel which allows the scientists and other from the twenty first century to travel back and mingle with the lawless Scottish clans of the Northern marches.

The protagonist is a scientist called Andrea Mitchell and she becomes romantically involved with a Sterkarm named Per.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This is the book, I really appreciate it :)